# Unable to start Activity java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-activity

my android app is unable to start the Activity for some reason, the Activity's name is Caperucita, but I can't see what the problem is, theres another activity like this that runs perfecty, and is Ricitos. maybe you can help me

the error in the logcat:

```
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.storyteller/com.example.storyteller.Caperucita}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.example.storyteller.Caperucita.onCreate(Caperucita.java:26)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 11 more
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 25 more
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
07-12 01:54:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 28 more
```

the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.storyteller"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.storyteller.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="AcercaDe"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>

    <activity android:name="Cuentos"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>

    <activity android:name="Ricitos"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>

    <activity android:name="Caperucita"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

the Xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <ScrollView

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

     <RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/rootRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="262dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.83"
    android:background="@drawable/caperucita_roja"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="800dp"
             android:layout_height="262dp"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/ib3"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                 android:onClick="contar"
                 android:src="@drawable/boton_contar_caperucita" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/ib2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ib3"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                 android:onClick="play"
                 android:src="@drawable/boton_play_caperucita" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ib2"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                 android:onClick="pause"
                 android:src="@drawable/boton_pausa_caperucita" />

         </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java file:

```
package com.example.storyteller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Caperucita extends Cuentos {

MediaPlayer mp;
int  posicion=0;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.caperucita);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


}

public void destruir() {
    if(mp!=null) 
        mp.release();
}


public void contar(View view){
    destruir ();
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.caperucitaroja);
    mp.start();

    }

public void pause(View view) {
    if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        posicion = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        mp.pause();

    }        
}




public void play(View view) {

    if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()==false) {
        mp.seekTo(posicion);
        mp.start();

    }   

}

protected void onResume() {
    if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying())
        mp.start();
    super.onResume();
}

public void onPause() {

    super.onPause(); 
if (mp != null)
    mp.pause(); 
}


public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    System.exit(0);     
    }

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitByBackKey();

        //moveTaskToBack(false);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

protected void exitByBackKey() {

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("¿De verdad desea salir? si lo hace no podrá reproducir el audio desde donde lo dejó")
    .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            finish();
            //close();


        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                       }
    })
      .show();

}


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the layout file inflated in your activity?

Comment: I just post it! @RenatoLochetti

Comment: Can you post Caperucita.java?

Comment: there it is man! @E.Odebugg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks the file size of your background is too big.  Try removing the background attribute in the relative layout below, and see if you get the crash.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="262dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.83"
    android:background="@drawable/caperucita_roja"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

To fix the problem you need more memory or you need to use less of it.  Getting more memory isn't really possible, but you can specify a larger heap size.  In your manifest, use the largeHeap attribute:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
```

You can read more about that attribute [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).

To decrease the amount of memory needed, you need to decrease the size of that background image.  I'd look at reducing the size of that image.  If reducing the dimensions is not possible, look into optimizing the image with a program like [PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/), which can help reduce the file's size without affecting the quality of the image.  [Here's a link to how to use PNGCrush from the command line.](http://davidwalsh.name/pngcrush)

Comment: that's the problem but why it doesn't work in Caperucita.java while in Ricitos.java it works? @Flynn81

Comment: @Whady - How big are the background graphics files? The problem is that the system ran out of memory while loading this layout.

Comment: 480x3969 in the Caperucita.java and 480x2461 in ricitos.java @TedHopp

Comment: Keep in mind, if your first activity is in the background while your second activity is in the foreground, the memory allocated for that first activity's drawable won't be garbage collected.  So even though it loads once, loading the image a second time seems to be crashing your app.

Comment: @Whady I updated the answer with two suggestions.  Definitely try the largeHeap attribute, I've had good luck with that before when confronted with out of memory exceptions.

Comment: I tried both solutions, but none of that solutions works to me :(, I don't know what to do @Flynn81

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the memory impact of your graphics files. From the stack trace, it's clear that the system ran out of memory while loading the `caperucita_roja` background. (That file, at 480x3969, is particularly large. Uncompressed in memory it will take up over 7MB. On many devices, that's a considerable fraction of the total memory available to an app.) Remember that Android devices are quite constrained in terms of available memory.

The training article [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) provides strategies that can help with this.